# What are some example javascript frameworks that people use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

I am really big fan of jQuery, but I don't see it as a framework for a site, more like a library.  I am looking for some sort of framework that will give me the tools to build really structured applications in javaScript.  I have found backbone.js, but find it somewhat confusing.  Is that a good one, and are there others similar to it?  an MVC pattern would be really cool, but I havent found anything.

Answer (score 2):

I use currently [RightJS](http://rightjs.org/) with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). It has worked out well for my purposes. I used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) + [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) previously. The current combo fits my style better (more barebone functionality instead of just DOM wrapper + UI plugins).

I know RightJS isn't that popular. The docs are adequate and the author is responsive. This makes up for that. :)

Some other alternatives:

- [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/)
- [MooTools](http://mootools.net/)
- [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

I'm sure there are plenty of more alternatives. It really comes down to your preferences and exact needs.

Personally I have been looking at Sencha's offerings ([ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/), [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)) lately. The latter is particularly interesting as it provides simple means to write cross-platform apps for mobile devices. Works great in iPad at least!

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Closure Library & Tools](http://code.google.com/closure/) is pretty good, and is the framework they use to build Gmail, Google Maps, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery and YUI 3: A Tale of Two JavaScript Libraries](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/10/27/jquery-and-yui-3-a-tale-of-two-javascript-libraries/) is a story about a jQuery developer that found that YUI3 was more "framework-like" and apt for his project.

I've been using YUI2 for years and it never disappointed me.

Answer (score 0):

If you like dynamic OOP languages like Ruby/Python, you should really check [RightJS](http://rightjs.org). It is very compact, fast and simple. RightJS is built fully on OOP paradigm and allows you to implement serious stuff in a serious but not boring way.

As for the dom part, it doesn't exactly uses MVC as is, but RightJS has OOP dom-wrappers, with inheritance and so one. That provides basically the same result, but with much less headache.

And if you're particularly interested in patterns, check this out https://github.com/rightjs/rightjs-patterns :)